# Parsing a sentence with the noun as the Predicator

Tags: syntax, syntax-trees, x-bar-theory

Can the sentence "That professor is a syntactician," in which the DP "a syntactician" is the predicator, be parsed like a normal sentence, using x-bar theory, the Predicate Shell and the DP Hypothesis? Why would a syntax tree not grow properly with this kind of sentence?

Comment: The predicator is "is".

Comment: I think the “is” is a copula be so it can’t be the predicator in this sentence.

Comment: If you want to say that copulas have no verb then there is no predicator.